Why converge energy vs. Ecut when k-points is the bottleneck?
I'm writing a report for a university modelling class where we have to determine equilibrium lattice parameters for various materials using DFT (Castep).
The first of these is Aluminium. What I am finding is that energy/atom vs. $E_\text{cut}$ converges far more quickly than energy/atom vs. k-points. Seeing as I don't have the time to run calculations with a large k-points grid, the number of k-points is acting as a bottleneck.
If I converge to around 5meV for k-points, is there any point converging to 1meV with $E_\text{cut}$, or should I simply go for 5meV there too? I ask because I have read some past reports, and I'm finding that other students have actually converged to different limits with $E_\text{cut}$ and k-points. I find that strange, as I would assume the lower convergence limit would act as a bottleneck.

You should really consider your choice of convergence criteria bearing in mind the eventual target calculation.  If your goal is to calculate a chemical reaction energy, then yes, the energy residual is appropriate (scaled from your test cell to the larger call of the target calculation).
However for many other calculations, perhaps the force or stress might be a more appropriate convergence criterion.  In that case the energy residual may well not be the same for, as these quantities frequently converge with cutoff more rapidly than the energy does.

Convergence is all about finding a suitable balance between cost and accuracy, and putting some sense of errors on your results.
Typically, you should have a think about the accuracy you require for the properties you care about (if you are converged to meV scale that is usually good, but if you want to stusy a feature on the meV scale.... needs more work)
